# User object Input into List of Data

Tags: c#, arrays, list, collections

I have a program trying to create a typical soda crate program, where the user can pick from a list and add into a array of 24, to represent the soda crate. But I want it to print out the list of objects in here to check if my code isn't broken before I continue. Except I can't get it to print out the data. I tried this with the foor loop but It didn't work

```
public class BeverageData
{
      public string Name { set; get; }
      public string Type { set; get; }
      public decimal Price { set; get; }
      public int Size { get; set; }
}

class Beverages : IEnumerable<BeverageData>
{
    public static void BeverageRun()
    {
        var crate = new List<BeverageData>();

        //Add some items to it
        var newBeverage= new BeverageData();
        newBeverage.Name = "Fanta";
        newBeverage.Price = 0.75M;
        newBeverage.Type = "Soda";
        crate.Add(newBeverage);

        crate.Add(new BeverageData() { Name = "Pepsi", Price = 0.25M, Type = "Soda" });

        //Prompting the user


        crate.Add(PromptUserForBeverage());

        foreach (var beverage in crate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(beverage);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveBeverage(string name)
    {

        var beverages = (from i in _items where String.Compare(i.Name, name, true) == 0 select i).FirstOrDefault();

        if (beverages != null)
            _items.Remove(beverages);
    }
    public IEnumerator<BeverageData> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    private readonly List<BeverageData> _items = new List<BeverageData>();

    static BeverageData PromptUserForBeverage()
    {
        var beverage = new BeverageData();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
        beverage.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        beverage.Price = GetDecimal("Enter cost: ");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter type: ");
        beverage.Type = Console.ReadLine();

        return beverage;
    }

    static decimal GetDecimal(string message)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            decimal result;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(input, out result))
                return result;

            Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Edit of Main Class:

```
public static object MyProperty
        {
            get { return beverages; }
            set { beverages = new Crate}
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var beverages = new Crate();
            ShowMenu();
            // Wait for input before closing
            Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void ShowMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[1] Add Bottle from existing list to Bottle Crate");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] Remove Bottle from Bottle Crate");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] Show Bottle Crate");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] Add Beverage to list");
            Console.WriteLine("[5] Remove Beverage from list");
            Console.WriteLine("[6] Sort Bottles in Bottle Crate");
            Console.WriteLine("[7] Sort Beverages in list");

            ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
            int selection;
            int.TryParse(info.KeyChar.ToString(), out selection);

            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1:
                    var numBevs = Math.Max(GetInt("How many beverages would you like to enter: "), 0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < numBevs; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\nEnter beverage #{i + 1} info");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
                        beverages.Add(Crate.GetBeverageFromUser());
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------\n");
                    }
                    numBevs = Math.Max(GetInt("How many would you like to be auto-added: "), 0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < numBevs; i++)
                    {
                        beverages.Add(Crate.GetRandomBeverage());
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------\n");
                    ShowMenu();
                    break;
                //case 2:
                //    Remove_Bottle();
                //    ShowMenu();
                //    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nHere are the contents of the crate:\n");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    beverages.PrintBeverages();
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    ShowMenu();
                    break;
                //case 4:
                //    BeverageRun();
                //    ShowMenu();
                //    break;
                //case 5:
                //    Remove_Beverage();
                //    ShowMenu();
                //    break;
                //case 6:
                //    Sort_Bottles();
                //    ShowMenu();
                //    break;
                //case 7:
                //    Sort_Beverages();
                //    ShowMenu();
                //    break;
                //case 8:
                //    Calc_Total();
                //    ShowMenu();
                //    break;
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    ShowMenu();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you try to print out the data, and it didn't work?

Comment: Is that your entire program? You left nothing out?

Comment: This is not the entire program, it has other parts I left out that are just filler, where I call this class.There are more or less nothing in the other classes of the program except structure. I tried to print the data here             
            foreach (var List in new List<BeverageData>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(List);
            }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the items to a local list (`crate`) instead of the class-level list (`_items`).

A couple of other problems you may run into are that you allow a string to be entered for the beverage type, which means there may be some errors on user entry (some may say "soda", some may say "pop", some may say "soft drink"). To resolve this, you could use an `enum` of pre-defined types for this field:

```
public enum BeverageType
{
    Soda,
    Juice,
    Water,
    Alcohol
}

public class Beverage
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public BeverageType Type { set; get; }
    public decimal Price { set; get; }
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} ({Type}) = {Price:C}";
    }
}
```

The other thing I noticed is that you don't provide a method to `Add` items to the crate, only to `Remove` them, so I added that below. I also added another `Remove` method that will remove a `Beverage` type, which is called from your original move method now.

We were also missing a `MaxCapacity` feature - you stated that a crate can only hold 24 items, but we weren't enforcing that anywhere. Now, when someone calls the `Add` method, it will show a message if the crate is full, and they will have to remove something first.

I also separated out the `PrintItems` method from the `BeverageRun` method, and I changed `BeverageRun` to `AddBeverageFromUser`, because I felt like it was doing too much - it was adding some pre-defined beverages, getting one from the user, and then printing them out. It's usually best to have a method just do one thing.

I also added a method called `AddRandomBeverage`, so we can populate the crate automatically, without forcing the user to do so much typing.

And finally, I added the `GetString` and `GetBeverageType` methods, to compliment your `GetDecimal` method for getting strongly typed information from the user.

Here's how the final `Crate` class came out:

```
class Crate : IEnumerable<Beverage>
{
    private readonly List<Beverage> crate = new List<Beverage>();
    private const int MaxItems = 24;
    private static readonly Random Rnd = new Random();

    public void Add(Beverage beverage)
    {
        if (crate.Count >= MaxItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The crate is full. Please remove an item first!");
        }
        else
        {
            crate.Add(beverage);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(string name)
    {
        Remove(crate.FirstOrDefault(i =>
            i.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
    }

    public void Remove(Beverage beverage)
    {
        if (crate.Contains(beverage)) crate.Remove(beverage);
    }

    public void PrintBeverages()
    {
        if (crate.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no items in the crate.");
        }
        else
        {
            crate.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Beverage> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return crate.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public static Beverage GetBeverageFromUser()
    {
        return new Beverage
        {
            Name = GetString("Enter name: "),
            Price = GetCurrency("Enter cost: "),
            Type = GetBeverageType("Enter type: ")
        };
    }

    public static Beverage GetRandomBeverage()
    {
        var names = new List<Beverage>
        {
            new Beverage {Name = "Coke", Price = .75m,
                Size = 12, Type = BeverageType.Soda},
            new Beverage {Name = "Pepsi", Price = .75m,
                Size = 12, Type = BeverageType.Soda},
            new Beverage {Name = "Sprite", Price = .75m,
                Size = 12, Type = BeverageType.Soda},
            new Beverage {Name = "Rootbeer", Price = .75m,
                Size = 12, Type = BeverageType.Soda},
            new Beverage {Name = "Orange Juice", Price = .5m,
                Size = 10, Type = BeverageType.Juice},
            new Beverage {Name = "Apple Juice", Price = .5m,
                Size = 10, Type = BeverageType.Juice},
            new Beverage {Name = "Grape Juice", Price = .5m,
                Size = 10, Type = BeverageType.Juice},
            new Beverage {Name = "Water", Price = .25m,
                Size = 20, Type = BeverageType.Water},
            new Beverage {Name = "Beer", Price = 2.75m,
                Size = 16, Type = BeverageType.Alcohol},
            new Beverage {Name = "Wine", Price = 3.5m,
                Size = 9, Type = BeverageType.Alcohol},
        };

        return names[Rnd.Next(names.Count)];
    }

    private static BeverageType GetBeverageType(string message)
    {
        BeverageType beverageType;

        Console.Write(message);

        while (!Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), true, out beverageType))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid beverage type");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.Write("Valid beverage types are: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(BeverageType))));
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.Write(message);
        }

        return beverageType;
    }

    private static string GetString(string message)
    {
        Console.Write(message);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static decimal GetCurrency(string message)
    {
        decimal result;
        Console.Write(message);

        while (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.Currency, 
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.Write(message);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

---

**Usage**

The usage of the `Crate` class might look something like this:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var beverages = new Crate();

    var numBevs = Math.Max(GetInt("How many beverages would you like to enter: "), 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < numBevs; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nEnter beverage #{i + 1} info");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
        beverages.Add(Crate.GetBeverageFromUser());
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------\n");
    }

    numBevs = Math.Max(GetInt("How many would you like to be auto-added: "), 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < numBevs; i++)
    {
        beverages.Add(Crate.GetRandomBeverage());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------\n");

    Console.WriteLine("\nHere are the contents of the crate:\n");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    beverages.PrintBeverages();
    Console.ResetColor();

    // Wait for input before closing
    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static int GetInt(string message)
{
    int result;
    Console.Write(message);

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.Write(message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: When using the code the GetInt in the main class generates a no context error. Don't we need an extra method in the crate class?

Comment: Yeah, I had that in the main class but didn't include it. I've now updated the answer with the `GetInt` method, and also updated the `Crate` class a little - added some color to the output. :)

Comment: `_items` is global?

Comment: I thought you were referring to `private readonly List<BeverageData> _items = new List<BeverageData>();`

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void BeverageRun()
{
    var crate = new List<BeverageData>();

    //Add some items to it
    var newBeverage= new BeverageData();
    newBeverage.Name = "Fanta";
    newBeverage.Price = 0.75M;
    newBeverage.Type = "Soda";

    crate.Add(newBeverage);
    crate.Add(new BeverageData() { Name = "Pepsi", Price = 0.25M, Type = "Soda" });

    //Prompting the user
    crate.Add(PromptUserForBeverage());

    foreach (var beverage in crate)
    {
        PrintBeverage(beverage);
    }
}

static string PrintBeverage(BeverageData beverage)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + beverage.Name + ", Price: $" + beverage.Price + ", Type: " + beverage.Type);
}
```

I assume you meant to loop through your `crate` list. Doing this will print the beverage object, however. Not the values of the beverage. So you'll probably have to change that if you want to see the values of your beverages.

## Edit

As [Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett) mentioned, you could also just override `ToString()` of `BeverageData`. Doing that would look like this.

```
public class BeverageData
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Type { set; get; }
    public decimal Price { set; get; }
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name: " + Name + ", Price: $" + Price + ", Type: " + Type;
    }
}
```

And in the foreach loop:

```
foreach (var beverage in crate)
{
    Console.WriteLine(beverage);
}
```

Comment: All this printed out are my namespace + this class file.

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer. I updated it to give you an example of how to print the values of the object rather than the object itself.

Comment: @JsonDork You could also override the `ToString()` method of `BeverageData`.

Comment: Ah. Aweswome! This works, now I have another problem. The user input is never saved and each time I enter a new one the previous user inputted object is deleted, is there any way to make them to remain and for the user to add lots of beverages?

Comment: If you want to save the user input (from the BeverageRun, I assume?) then you should be adding it to the global list `_items` instead of the local list `crate` (which is currently recreated every time the method is called)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print out the items of a newly created list (of zero items).  Unsurprisingly, nothing is printed.

Comment: You added items to your locally declare "crate", but then are attempting to iterate through yet another new List< Beverage >().  Jun's answer above demonstrates what you probably want to do:    foreach (var item in crate)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }